# Airflow gives error ImportError: No module named MySQLdb upon changing its config file for celery

Tags: mysql, celery, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have installed airflow with celery in my ec2 linux instance and airflow is working like a charm. Now when I made changes in its config file to use celery with airflow it is throwing the following error.

```
[2020-04-03 07:24:57,234] {settings.py:253} INFO - settings.configure_orm(): Using pool settings. pool_size=5, max_overflow=10, pool_recycle=1800, pid=4851
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 25, in <module>
    from airflow.configuration import conf
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    settings.initialize()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/settings.py", line 377, in initialize
    configure_orm()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/settings.py", line 266, in configure_orm
    engine = create_engine(SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN, **engine_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/__init__.py", line 479, in create_engine
    return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 87, in create
    dbapi = dialect_cls.dbapi(**dbapi_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/mysqldb.py", line 118, in dbapi
    return __import__("MySQLdb")
ImportError: No module named MySQLdb
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
pip install MySQL-python
```

Should fix this